# Selecting data from XML field in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I am attempting to extract data from an XML field in a MSSQL server database, sample XML below

```
<Results>
    <Result name="A" ID="1" category="C" resultLevel="">
        <Value>01/01/1900</Value>
    </Result>
```

Ideally the select statement will return the following as query results

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/1900 |
| B | 01/01/1910 |

Then based on the query results, add a where clause to return specific values based on the name.

Comment: what flavor of SQL is this? MSSQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, or what?

Comment: Apologies, ill add to original post. Its MSSQL.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Where does `B` come from? Is it another row of XML, or is it within the same XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a trivial task.

XQuery `.nodes()` and `.value()` methods to the rescue.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Results>
    <Result name="A" ID="1" category="C" resultLevel="">
        <Value>2021-03-10</Value>
    </Result>
    <Result name="B" ID="1" category="C" resultLevel="">
        <Value>2021-03-12</Value>
    </Result>
</Results>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [name]
    , c.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS [value]
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Results/Result') AS t(c)
WHERE c.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'DATE') = '2021-03-10';
```

**Output**

```
+------+------------+
| name |   value    |
+------+------------+
| A    | 2021-03-10 |
+------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks you- I have been able to apply this logic with the desired output. To add a where clause, would you recommend using another temporary table to contain the name and value or can this be handled in the existing query?

Comment: @TryingToCode, it is not clear what you are asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: If I wanted to add a WHERE clause, to only extract the value (2021-03-10) based on the name (A) could this be added to the @tbl SELECT statement.

Comment: @TryingToCode, I updated the answer with a proper `WHERE` clause.